# What is the name of these beautiful white trees?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I found these beautiful white trees in an unknown video.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do a [Google Image search](https://www.google.com/imghp) with the picture in the question, you'll see the screenshot is from the 2000 movie [The Patriot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187393/) starring Mel Gibson. The movie's [filming locations](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187393/locations?ref_=tt_ql_dt_6) were mainly scattered around South Carolina, on the southern East Coast of the United States. I've spent a lot of time in the region, and the gray-ish fluffy stuff hanging off the branches is almost certainly [Spanish moss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_moss) (*Tillandsia usneoides*), which is very common in the area.

[image: Spanish Moss]

While it is more difficult to identify the tree, as the bark and leaves are not clearly visible up close, a good educated guess based on the size and shape of the tree would be [live oak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_virginiana) (*Quercus virginiana*), which also happens to be one of the primary hosts of Spanish moss.

[image: live oak]

Comment: Plot twist. I was on set. The Spanish moss on the large tree in front of Ben Martin’s (Mel Gibson) house was hung by hand using a cherry picker. Spanish moss is found closer to the coast. This scene was shot in the Rock Hill area of South Carolina